# Duplicating everything In a List of Nodes

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, nodes

This method, doubleList is supposed to take a list and repeat the sequence of nodes again. LinkedIntList is supposed to behave like a ListNode of integers. For instance, [1]->[2]->[3] will be [1]->[2]->[3]->[1]->[2]->[3]. While I managed to get it to work with a helper method, add(), I am supposed to not use a helper. How should I approach this?

Here is the ListNode:

```
public class ListNode {
    public int data;       // data stored in this node
    public ListNode next;  // link to next node in the list

    // post: constructs a node with data 0 and null link
    public ListNode() {
        this(0, null);
    }

    // post: constructs a node with given data and null link
    public ListNode(int data) {
        this(data, null);
    }

    // post: constructs a node with given data and given link
    public ListNode(int data, ListNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Here is LinkedIntList w/ the helper that works:

```
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;  // first value in the list

    // post: constructs an empty list
    public LinkedIntList() {
        front = null;
    }

    // post: doubles size of array by appending copy of original into end
    public void doubleList() {
        ListNode current = front; // front of this list
        LinkedIntList other = new LinkedIntList(); // stores copy of the original list
        ListNode temp = other.front; // front of other list

        while (current != null) { // puts a copy of current into new list
            other.add(current.data); // adds data to it
            current = current.next;
        }

        temp = other.front; // resets other list to beginning
        while (temp != null) { // readds that copy onto end of this list
            add(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;       
        }   
    }

    // post: appends the given value to the end of the list (helper)
    public void add(int value) {
        if (front == null) {
            front = new ListNode(value);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new ListNode(value);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here's my attempt w/o using the helper. What is wrong with this? It seems to not append the other list onto the end of this one.

```
   public void doubleList() {
        ListNode current = front; // front of this list
        LinkedIntList other = new LinkedIntList(); // stores copy of the original list
        ListNode temp = other.front; // front of other list

        while (current != null) { // puts copy of current onto temp
            temp = new ListNode(current.data);
            temp = temp.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
        temp = other.front; // reset temp to front
        while (temp != null) { // goes through temp to add to end of current
            current = new ListNode(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are two problems with this the front of other is never set and the nodes in the temp list are never linked. In your other solution, both were taken care of and that's why it worked

Comment: What are the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your second `doubleList()` method :

These lines :

```
    LinkedIntList other = new LinkedIntList(); // stores copy of the original list
    ListNode temp = other.front; // front of other list
```

Are equivalent to :

```
    LinkedIntList other = new LinkedIntList(); // stores copy of the original list
    ListNode temp = null;
```

Since `front` is null in a new list.

In addition,

```
        temp = new ListNode(current.data);
        temp = temp.next;
```

is equivalent to :

```
        temp = new ListNode(current.data);
        temp = null;
```

Which means you are creating nodes that are not connected to each other.

In order to link the nodes, you must update temp.next.

So you can create the duplicated nodes this way :

```
    current = front; // front of this list
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode frontOther = null;
    while (current != null) {
        temp = new ListNode(current.data);
        if (prev != null) {
            prev.next = temp; // link the previous node to the new node
        } else {
            frontOther = temp; // keep a reference to the first node of the new nodes
        }
        prev = temp;
        current = current.next;
    }
```

Then you can connect them to the end of the original list :

```
    current = front; // front of this list
    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = frontOther; // link the end of the original list to the duplicated nodes
```